# no match for operator ! =

Tags: c++11, vector

When i compile the code i get a error 'No match for operator !=' (operand type are 'int' and 'std::vector::iterator' on line 8 
But when i use the same operator on line 41 there seems to be no problem

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> Heap;
int Size;
auto k =0;
void max_heapify(vector<int> vect)
{
    int vect_size= vect.size()/2;
for(k=vect_size; k != vect.end();k--)//line 8
    {
if(vect[(2*k)+1]>vect[k])
        {
    vect[k]=vect[2*k]+1;
        }
else if(vect[2*k]+2>vect[k])
{
     vect[k]=vect[2*k]+2;
}
    }
 }
 int main()
 {

int items;
cout<<"Enter the size of the heap"<<endl;
cin>>Size;
cout<<"Enter the first element(root) and then the left and the right             elements accordingly"<<endl;
for(int i=1;i<=Size;i++)
{
cout<<"Enter the"<<" "<<i<<" "<<"element";
cin>>items;
Heap.push_back(items);
}
for(auto j=Heap.begin();j!=Heap.end();j++)
    {
    cout<<*j<<endl;
    }
max_heapify(Heap);

for(auto j=Heap.begin();j!=Heap.end();j++)//line 41
    {
    cout<<*j<<endl;
    }

    }
```

Comment: My oh my, as an aside, PLEASE make variable names lowercase, initialize things, scope things properly....

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing an integer to an end iterator. I am not sure what you expect that for loop to do. I don't think you know either.

Talk to yourself out loud, describe what it does. It will help you.

Comment: so should i compare that with a iterator this way vector<int>::iterator it;                   for(it=vect.size()/2;it != vect.begin();it--)

Comment: Just traverse it like an array. You are just storing integers, so just do for(int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) { vect[i]....}

Comment: Thank you, @OmidCompSCI that seems to work but what i am actually trying to do is trying to implement a heap using vectors and i need the start with the middle element of the array.

Comment: @Ayush.S, yes what's wrong with doing what I suggested?